# Asp.net MVC changing javascript won't apply

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Just started on ASP.NET MVC and I noticed a strange behaviour on updating a javascipt.

**_AppLayout.cshtml**

```
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/scripts/app.js")"></script>
```

The `@Url.Content` is working, but when I modify the `app.js` the modification will only apply when I replace the `script src=...` line. Why is that? Has ASP.NET some kind of cache? Which way will load the file without the modifications?

**Edit**
Is it necessary to use bundles so the changes will apply?
Regards

Comment: Browser cache...Bundling will help with the task of 'cache-busting'.

Comment: @DavidTansey thanks for response! Is this the only way to fix this cache? Because it's really ignoring while developing some javascript!:o

Comment: OMG, really embarrassing but I just figured out that a simple refresh does the job...

Comment: During development you should be able to use CTRL-F5 or similar to refresh the cached items.  https://www.getfilecloud.com/blog/2015/03/tech-tip-how-to-do-hard-refresh-in-browsers/#.Vl3hN1WrTRY

Comment: It also helps to [disable the browser cache during development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047794/how-do-i-ensure-my-script-file-isnt-cached-when-debugging-a-vs-mvc-website/33048502#33048502).

Comment: Thanks for your response all, definitely usefull